# Angularjs toggle div visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, toggle

I am trying to toggle a div text on click of a button. I tried taking a scope variable and toggeling classname based on the variable. Where am I making the mistake [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nw5ndzrt/340/)

```html
<button ng-click="toggle()">test</button>
<div ng-class="{{state}}">
  hello test
</div>
```

```js
function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.state = vis;
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    state = !state;
  };
}
```

```css
.vis {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can simplify this a lot like so

```
<button ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">test </button>
<div ng-show="showDiv" >
    hello test
</div>
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17957/)

Unless you need the specific ng-class to toggle in which case you can do something like

```
<button ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">test </button>
<div ng-class="{'vis' : showDiv }" >
    hello test
</div>
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17961/)

(just make sure you're using a newer version of angular for this)

Comment: @Chandana which part are you referring to? Becuase that fiddle you are using is not hooked up correctly.

Comment: @Chandana you did not bootstrap that fiddle, check my example for working fiddle. I have added working fiddle examples for both methods.

Answer (score 18):

I have changed your directive..

**html**

```
    <button ng-click="toggle()">test </button>
<div ng-show="state" >
    hello test
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function ctrl($scope) {    

    $scope.toggle = function () {
      $scope.state = !$scope.state;
    }; }
```

see complete code here 
http://jsfiddle.net/nw5ndzrt/345/

Comment: Selected answer doesn't work. This does for anyone who may find this question.

Answer (score 2):

*Another approach...*
Use **ng-switch** 
 You can toggle through multiple divs without the css hassle...

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <button ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">test </button>
 <div ng-switch="showDiv" >
   <div ng-switch-default>
  hello you
   </div>
   <div ng-switch-when=true>
  hello me
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: "message": "ReferenceError: angular is not defined",