# Toggle div with Angular 6

Tags: angular, toggle, angular6

I'm new to Angular and want to start with something simple to learn.

I'm currently developing a form and have divs which I need to toggle upon user selection. Do I need to create Angular 6 component to create such a toggle function?

How can I do the toggle - whether with component or without (if possible)?

Thanks

Comment: Just use `*ngIf` and some variable as per conditions

Comment: Thanks @Pardeep Is that angularJs or Angular 6? Can I just install Angular 6 into existing application and use the above code within a MVC view template?

Comment: `*ngIf` is in Angular (2/4/5/6) not in AngularJs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
const isOpened = true;

<div *ngIf="isOpened">
<form> </form>
<div>

<div *ngIf="!isOpened">
<form> </form>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Anthony Is that angularJs or Angular 6? Can I just install Angular 6 into existing application and use the above code within a MVC view template?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I have installed new angular project and moved its files into my existing project. Then applied your code and it doesn't work. I also used the example from this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830190/angularjs-toggle-div-visibility and it doesn't work either. I am not sure it is because the angular in my project not working or I am missing something in my template to make angular working.

Comment: it works for all version of angular from 2 through 6.