# div toggle on checkbox checked and unchecked angular 6

Tags: angular6

> **component.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-check position-absolute">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" [checked] = true >
    </div>
    <app-stackbar-chart [data]="exp_month_data"></app-stackbar-chart>
    <app-stackbar-chart [data]="exp_data_performance"></app-stackbar-chart>
</div>
```

> **question description**

I want to toggle these two divs(app-stackbar-chart) on check and uncheck of that checkbox

Comment: You can use *ngIf for that. Something like *ngIf="!checked".

Comment: i tried but its not working.. can you please post how should i implement

Comment: Please refer this link may be it's help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946102/toggle-div-with-angular-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

component.ts

```
//declare variable for chacked/unchecked

isChecked:boolean = true;
```

component.ts

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-check position-absolute">
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="isChecked =! isChecked" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" [checked] = true >
    </div>
    <app-stackbar-chart *ngIf="isChecked" [data]="exp_month_data"></app-stackbar-chart>
    <app-stackbar-chart *ngIf="!isChecked" [data]="exp_data_performance"></app-stackbar-chart>
</div>
```